# When searching Git diffs for a term, can I only show the line the term is on?

Tags: git

I'm doing some CSS cleanup and want to find where a class was used in our code, to ensure that it was in fact used in our code, and not in our CMS or the like.

We're using Git so I'm using the following to search code diffs that contain the search term I'm looking for, **scrollerWrapper**.

```
git log -GscrollerWrapper -p
```

With the `-p` flag I'm getting the actual changes to the file, but in some cases it's returning files that are thousands of lines long. Ideally I would only want to see the line(s) that the term I'm searching for is on (even better if I could see *x* lines before/after the line).

I've checked [the documentation for git-log](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) but I don't see a relevant parameter.

Is it possible to either pass some additional parameter that would limit the diff to just the lines containing my search term, or run a different query that would do this?

Thank you!

Comment: This sounds like [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378). Could you tell us about what it's being piped into and why?

Comment: Based upon your proposed answer I think you figured it out. The bit about piping into something else was only if I couldn't do what I wanted to do just with Git tools. I'll update the question to tweak that sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest thing to do is to use the search facilities built into your [pager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_pager), which is the thing that lets you scroll through the text of `git log`.

For most pagers type `/` followed by whatever you want to search for. So run `git log -GscrollerWrapper -p` as normal, then type `/`, then `scrollerWrapper`. This will advance to the first appearance of `scrollerWrapper`. Hitting `n` will take you to the next one.

Comment: Wow, I really like this, and gives me a good reason to look into the pager functionality further.

Comment: @JamesSkemp Pagers are great, and are relevant to many tools.

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe the `git log` output to `grep`. On Windows you can do this with Git Bash. `grep` has parameters to specify how much context to give for each matched line.

Comment: ...but then you don't know what line is part of what commit.

Comment: @Schwern ...nor which line is part of which file. I thought of this after I posted my answer and have been doing some research to find a reasonable solution. No luck so far ;-(

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, I always defer to the venerable Gitk whenever I need to search a repository. Luckily, if you know your way around the `ps` command, you can see the actual commands that Gitk is running in the background when you do a search. Gitk offers a search ability that scans the repository history for adds/removals of a string (which I believe is what you're looking for). The command that it is actually running in the background is `git diff-tree`, which is a wildly complex command with approximately 47 billion options.

Anyway, I think something along the lines of `git diff-tree -r -U3 -Ssearch_string <tree-ish search target>` would work for you.

- `-r` makes the whole thing search recursively
- `-U` is for outputting a unified diff, where the `3` is the number of lines of context
- `-S` is for the actual search string. The format looks funny typing it this way, and don't forget you might need to escape special characters depending on what you're searching for
- `<tree-ish search target>` is *where* you want to search from. You can just put the commit hash of your current `HEAD` or `master` or any other tree-ish ref.

If you've ever generated unified diffs from git on the command line before, the output should be pretty familiar here, and will look something like:

```
$ git diff-tree -r -U3 -Sexisting_user 599479fc43401942cedef7187677fa222ec54c94
599479fc43401942cedef7187677fa222ec54c94
diff --git a/src/AppBundle/Controller/SubscriptionController.php b/src/AppBundle/Controller/SubscriptionController.php
index 3670973..55de07a 100644
--- a/src/AppBundle/Controller/SubscriptionController.php
+++ b/src/AppBundle/Controller/SubscriptionController.php
@@ -23,28 +23,17 @@ class SubscriptionController extends AbstractController
         $form->handleRequest($request);

         if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
-            $existing_user = $this->get('user_dao')->getUserByEmail($newly_invited_user->getEmail());
...
```

This should get you everything you need, commit ref, line number and context.

Comment: Oh, or just use Gitk

Comment: Hmm. 1) So I was behind on Git so I didn't have Gitk, but once I updated the search didn't behave as expected. Probably requires some more effort on my part. 2) So I used `git log` and grabbed the last commit hash and while it runs for a second I get no results. The documentation suggests I can do this, and it would search the parents of the commit hash I provide. Am I missing something? `git diff-tree -r -U3 -SscrollerWrapper 2f9c3637a96f7aa3893d1715c69a28c5c092a9a0`

Comment: The format looks correct, I just can't comment on the hash at all without knowing the repo. Basically, the hash you want to provide should point to a commit that _contains_ all of the commits you want to search within it's history. Typically, this is `master` or some other trunk-like branch.

Comment: Hmm. The last commit was in master so ... weird. Thanks!